# WCF multiple host header with 'same port' causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have read alot of articles to fix this problem but I am unable to solve it.

**Scenario**
I have a website which has a WCF service and 2 host headers

1. spin-localhost
2. spin-localhost.worldwide.co.uk (changed to spin-localhost2)

But with same port **44001** I can access spin-localhost service but cannot access spin-localhost.worldwide.co.uk (now spin-localhost2).

**Coding**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.CilsDataReceiveBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WindowsAuth" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.CilsDataReceiveBehavior" name="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.CilsDataReceive">
        <endpoint address="http://spin-localhost:44001/Services/CilsDataReceive.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="WindowsAuth" contract="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.ICilsDataReceive" />
        <endpoint address="http://spin-localhost.worldwide.co.uk:44001/Services/CilsDataReceive.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="WindowsAuth" contract="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.ICilsDataReceive" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://spin-localhost:44001" />
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

the above solution failed I tried with factory

```
public class CustomHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses[0]);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I am using /Net 3.5 rather 4.

**References**
http://www.sieena.com/blog/archive/2011/02/01/wcf-service-in-iis-with-multiple-host-headers.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2008/02/11/how-can-wcf-support-multiple-iis-binding-specified-per-site.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2007/06/15/supporting-multiple-iis-bindings-per-site.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/9e248455-1c4d-4c5c-851c-79d9c1631e21/

And many more....

**Update 1:** After further testing it seems there is an error with worldwide.bbc.co.uk so i changed the name and binding to spin-localhost2.

```
<endpoint address="http://spin-localhost2:44001/Services/CilsDataReceive.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="WindowsAuth" contract="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.ICilsDataReceive" />
```

I can access the first service with spin-localhost but spin-localhost2 gives 401, 401 and then 400 (not found). checked it with Fiddler.

**Solution** (have not tested yet):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.CilsDataReceiveBehavior">
          <!--          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WindowsAuth" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.CilsDataReceiveBehavior" name="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.CilsDataReceive">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="WindowsAuth" contract="Bbc.Ww.SalesProjections.UI.Services.ICilsDataReceive"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: By the way, do you really need to configure host headers on your server to access it by the same name ? The only difference being that the domain-less address will only be available from a computer inside the same domain, and that everyone outside the domain should use the full address. If you can, try with no specified host headers in IIS configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF with .NET under vesion 4 doesn't support multiple host header IIS hosting, there are workarounds for this, which, depending on your .NET version are more or less complicated.

WCF in .NET 4.0 supports this as an opt-in feature enabled by using `<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />` in the configuration.

Everything is thoroughly explained there : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2008/02/11/how-can-wcf-support-multiple-iis-binding-specified-per-site.aspx

Comment: Like I said in the comment to the question : Do you really need to configure specific host headers for this ?

Comment: do I need endpoint properties if i were to use .NET 4 and your stated property?

Comment: That's fine I have upgraded my project to .Net 4.0 so problem fixed :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

WCF with IIS will support multiple endpoints with *different* relative addresses as [shown in this blog post](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/02/multiple-endpoints-for-wcf-service.html) but I don't think IIS will support different host headers on the same port and in the same web site/application. Try creating separate IIS web sites, one per host header and use a separate serviceModel config for each service. That way you can use the same port for the services you create.

Comment: IIS does support different host headers on same port. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx?mfr=true .NET 4.0 has solution for it but unfortunately I am on .Net 3.5

Comment: Although IIS is capable of assigning a host hame per unique IP address within a web site, WCF won't support this configuration. Look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx). Each IIS IP address assignment equals a separate base address but the post states: "You can also have multiple base addresses for a service, but each service is allowed only one base address for each transport."